# Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0) error

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to use `like` operator to search database data and display in a jTable but I keep getting

> the Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is
> 0).

This is my code below.

```
private void jButton_searchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
//button captures data from textbox and displays on table
    
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    
    String Search = jTextField_search.getText();
    try {   
String query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE Title like ' %`?`%' " ; 
ps = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
 ps.setString(1, Search);       
   
 rs =  ps.executeQuery();
        
       jTable2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);   
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest binding the wildcard expression as a string to a standalone `?` placeholder in your prepared statement:

```java
String Search = jTextField_search.getText();
try {   
    String query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE Title LIKE ?"; 
    ps = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, "%" + Search + "%");
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    jTable2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
} 
catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);   
}
```

I don't really know why you are using backticks in your `LIKE` expression.  Backticks are used by MySQL (and perhaps a few other) databases to escape objects, such as column and table names.  It probably doesn't make sense for your query.

To explain your current error, in MySQL placing `?` surrounded by backticks will escape the binding placeholder and instead make it a literal `?`.  This could explain the complaint that you have no parameters.